# AWS Cost Categories: Failed to create/update Cost Category

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

Someone encountered this error while updating or creating a new cost category? This is my first time encountering this and I can't find any documentation or solution in the internet.

> Validation error
> Failed to create Cost Category: Effective start can only be first day of a month at 00:00:00 UTC

Thanks!

Comment: did you checked the restrictions of cost category https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-limits.html#limits-categories, plus as I can see your entered value failed to satisfy the contracts of that particular service https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-cost-management/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html

Comment: I just tried to Update/Create again, and it worked. Don't really know what happened. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bug in AWS Console. because I checked from json and found that it sends incorrect "EffectiveStart" data.

`{"RuleVersion":"CostCategoryExpression.v1","Rules":[{"Type":"REGULAR","Value":"Dev","Rule":{"Tags":{"Key":"Application","Values":["Dev"],"MatchOptions":["EQUALS"]}}}],"EffectiveStart":"2022-07-31T00:00:00Z","Name":"Dev"}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).